# QFIELD digitizing window never closes

Tags: vector, fields-attributes, digitizing, qfield

I use QFIELD on Android 5.1.1 (Samsung Galaxy), I tried several versions of QFIELD without solving my problem:

when I click on a vector I just created, the attribute window opens on the right side of the screen and never slides back ... and hides the pencil button which allows to digitize!

Has someone had this problem before ?

I created my project on QGIS 2.12.3

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and it is quite annoying. I worked it out by clicking in an area where there is no features. You should zoom out and seek for an area without feature. Aftewards the attribute windows could slides back.